# How to open specific page in the app on clicking Push Notification?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am working on an Android app using cordova and implemented a push notification system using the cordova `$PushPlugin`. 
My PushPlugin code ([source](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)):

```
module.run(function($rootScope,$cordovaPush) {

var androidConfig = {
"senderID": "replace_with_sender_id",
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
  // Success
}, function(err) {
  // Error
})

$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
  switch(notification.event) {
    case 'registered':
      if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
        alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
      }
      break;

    case 'message':
      // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
      alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
      break;

    case 'error':
      alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
      break;

    default:
      alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
      break;
  }
});


// WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
$cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
  // Success!
}, function(err) {
  // Error
})

}, false);
});
```

On clicking the push notification received, I want to redirect the user to a specified page in my app. I referred [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213)(based on phonegap pushplugin) but could not figure out a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple solution without using any angular routes.

```
case 'message':
if (notification.foreground === false){
   window.location = '#/abc';
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check structure of object `notification`, you will see that there is an attribute `foreground`, which will be false when you come to app from clicking notification. You can use that to put your logic

```
case 'message':
 if(notification.foreground === false){
   //add logic for navigation to your specific page i.e $state.go('myPage')
 }
```

Comment: I tried this  `if(notification.foreground === false){ $location.path = ('/abc');}` and added `$location` in module.run function too. But on clicking the notification the redirect fails and I get redirected to the main page instead. Btw I am using ngRouter.